# Delete last input even number from array using stack

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

I'm a beginner at C programming. I'm making a program that will input numbers and delete the last input even number from the array using stack or the push-pop method.

The problem is I can't pop the last even number and I don't know what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int top = -1;
int stack[MAX];

void deleteEven(int num[], int i);

int main() {
  int num[100];
  int i, size;

  printf("\n-----------------\n\n");
  printf("Enter size of array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    top++;
    stack[top] = num[i];
  }
  printf("\nList: ");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", num[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("Even: ");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
      printf("%d, ", num[i]);
    }
  }
  deleteEven(num, i);
  return 0;
}

void deleteEven(int num[], int i) {
  printf("\nAnswer: ");
  if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
    stack[top--];
  }

  for (int j = top; j >= 0; --j) {
    printf("%d, ", stack[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the expected *and actual* output? And have you tried to step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: And please indent your code properly.

Comment: The output should be the array with the deleted even number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implement the working one in C with implementing on your code, you can see below. I added `int checkEven(int stack[], int stackSize)` function which control the array if there is any even number or not. If not, so end the problem with returning 0 or whatever your error code is, other side if there is even number it returns the index of it and `deleteEven` function swipe the array (`stack`). It working for `size of 5` array but you can fix it. I use 5 for easy testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX 5

int top = -1;
int stack[MAX];

void deleteEven(int num[], int indexOfEven);
int checkEven(int stack[], int stackSize);

int main() {
  int num[5];
  int i, size;

  printf("\n-----------------\n\n");
  printf("Enter size of array: ");
  scanf("%d", &size);

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    top++;
    stack[top] = num[i];
  }
  printf("\nList: ");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", num[i]);
  }
  printf("\n===stack===");
  for( i = 0; i <size; i++){
    printf("%d ", stack[i]);
  }

  int indexOfEven = checkEven(stack,5);
  if(indexOfEven >= 0){
    printf("This sequence has even number");

    printf("the index => %d ",indexOfEven);

    deleteEven(stack, indexOfEven);



  }else{
    printf("this sequence has no even number");
    /*
      no even number
      exit
    */
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}

int checkEven(int stack[], int stackSize){
  for(int i = stackSize - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(stack[i] % 2 == 0){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
} 

void deleteEven(int num[], int indexOfEven) {

  int simpleArray[5];
  for(int t = 0; t < 5; t++){
    simpleArray[t] = num[t];
  }

  int c;
  for (c = indexOfEven; c < 4; c++)
    simpleArray[c] = num[c+1];


  for (c = 0; c < 4; c++){
    printf("\n%d\n", simpleArray[c]);
  }

}
```

So far you see the `O(n)` implementation of it with array but you describe that you want to implement it with `push() - pop() - peek()` stack mechanism. I want to write sudo code for fully `Stack` implementation.

```
let it inputs be 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 7 

describe inputSize
describe mainStack
describe helperStack

read inputs to mainStack
```

> show stacks
>
> `mainStack -> [1-2-3-5-7]`
>
> `helperStack -> []`

```
while mainStack.peek() != NULL :
    if mainStack.peek() % 2 == 0:      // even number
       mainStack.pop()
       break the loop
    else:
       describe popValue = mainStack.pop()
       helperStack.push( popValue ) 


if inputSize == helperStack: 
     // no even number 
     // so nothing break the loop, every value is odd so, all there is another stack 
     // finish program with error code or return main array / inputs
```

> show stacks
>
> `mainStack -> [ 1 ]`
>
> `helperStack -> [ 3 5 7 ]`

now `pop()` the all `helperStack` and push it to `mainStack`

```
while helperStack.peek() != NULL:  
    mainStack.push( helperStack.pop() )
```

> show stacks
>
> ```
>  mainStack -> [ 1 3 5 7 ]
>
>  helperStack -> [ ]
> ```

Return `mainStack` as array format.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last loop before the call to `deleteEven` will increment `i` until the end of the `stack` array regardless the last number is even or not, because all you do is checking if the current number is even and then printing it, and right after that going to the next one. that will iterate through all the numbers which will result in calling `deleteEven` with the last index of the array.

how about going from the last element of the array to index `0` (backwards) and printing the first encounter with even number?

Also, not really sure why you're using two different arrays and copying elements one by one after using `scanf`.